# How to fix "Could not find tag for codec timed_id3 in stream #0"?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

**ffmpeg** gives me the following error for some videos.

```
Could not find tag for codec timed_id3 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

I pass this command:

```py
command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-hide_banner',
    '-loglevel', 'panic',
    '-i', input_file,
    '-vf', "scale='trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480'",
    '-c:a', 'copy',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-c:s', 'mov_text',
    '-scodec', 'srt',
    '-map', '0',
    '-map', '-0:a:1',
    '-map', '-0:a:2',
    output_file,
]
```

I already know that this issue related to `-map` argument but I use it for a reason.

**The reason**: I want to encode all videos into 480p by:

1. Keeping all embedded subtitles
2. Keeping English or First audio track

May you please help me to perform that?